# How do I change text of a product template in a WooCommerce theme?

Tags: customization, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change 'Out of stock' to 'Sold' on my product pages when a product is gone. What template should I look at to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this a while back by following this [WooCommerce tutorial](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/202845976-How-to-Change-In-Stock-Out-of-Stock-Text):

> There may come a time where you would like change the text displayed
>   on a product's page when it is In Stock or Out of Stock.
>
> Simply add the following code to the 'custom functions' area of your
>   `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Change In Stock / Out of Stock Text
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

> Now simply change the **Available!** and **Sold Out** text to be whatever you
>   would like.

Use a custom function in the `functions.php` file. If you're editing those core WooCommerce templates, you risk losing your changes on plugin upgrades. If you have a custom function in that `functions.php` file, it should work regardless of plugin upgrades, theme updates, etc.